# Exception while running activiti-rest.war

Tags: activiti

Can anyone explain the procedure how to run activiti-rest.war,i am using postgres database.
I copied the war file into tomcat webapps while running it shows this error,one more thing i am not using spring framework,i change the db.properties file with postgres configuration,still what and where to configure the settings.Explain clearly both in tomcat and jboss

```
org.activiti.engine.ProcessEngines initProcessEnginFromResource
SEVERE: Exception while initializing process engine :couldn't check if tables are already present using metadata:
### Error getting a new connection.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/activiti
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/activiti
org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: couldn't check if tables are already present using metadata:
### Error getting a new connection.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/activiti
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/activiti
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSqlSession.isTablePresent(DbSqlSession.java:890)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSqlSession.isEngineTablePresent(DbSqlSession.java:854)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSqlSession.dbSchemaUpdate(DbSqlSession.java:806)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSqlSession.performSchemaOperationsProcessEngineBuild(DbSqlSession.java:1100)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.SchemaOperationsProcessEngineBuild.execute(SchemaOperationsProcessEngineBuild.java:25)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:24)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:60)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:32)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.ProcessEngineImpl.<init>(ProcessEngineImpl.java:75)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.buildProcessEngine(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.java:311)
        at org.activiti.engine.ProcessEngines.buildProcessEngine(ProcessEngines.java:194)
        at org.activiti.engine.ProcessEngines.initProcessEnginFromResource(ProcessEngines.java:167)
        at org.activiti.engine.ProcessEngines.init(ProcessEngines.java:98)
        at org.activiti.engine.ProcessEngines.getProcessEngine(ProcessEngines.java:224)
        at org.activiti.engine.ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine(ProcessEngines.java:217)
        at org.activiti.rest.servlet.ActivitiServletContextListener.contextInitialized(ActivitiServletContextListener.java:39)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1655)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
### Error getting a new connection.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/activiti
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/activiti
        at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:23)
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.getConnection(DefaultSqlSession.java:222)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSqlSession.isTablePresent(DbSqlSession.java:867)
        ... 29 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/activiti
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
        at org.apache.ibatis.datasource.unpooled.UnpooledDataSource.doGetConnection(UnpooledDataSource.java:181)
        at org.apache.ibatis.datasource.unpooled.UnpooledDataSource.doGetConnection(UnpooledDataSource.java:176)
        at org.apache.ibatis.datasource.unpooled.UnpooledDataSource.getConnection(UnpooledDataSource.java:80)
        at org.apache.ibatis.datasource.pooled.PooledDataSource.popConnection(PooledDataSource.java:371)
        at org.apache.ibatis.datasource.pooled.PooledDataSource.getConnection(PooledDataSource.java:80)
        at org.apache.ibatis.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.openConnection(JdbcTransaction.java:131)
        at org.apache.ibatis.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.getConnection(JdbcTransaction.java:58)
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.getConnection(DefaultSqlSession.java:220)
        ... 30 more
```

Comment: It seems like you don't have postgres driver in \WEB-INF\lib folder

Answer (score 0):

The tomcat server, on which you are deploying the `activiti-rest.war`, should contain the postgres JDBC driver jar file in its lib folder.

You can get the [postgre JDBC driver here](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html).

Comment: Thankx joshi my problem solved but i run rest uri http://localhost:9090/activiti-rest/service/process-definitions method:get  i get the this  response "Status Code: 403 Forbidden".

Comment: All `rest-apis` provided by Activiti require basic authentication. Use respective user credential for the apis such as for admin related `apis` use `kermit` user.

Comment: Put this in a separate question as it does not adhere to subject line.